# Is there any way to know how much time Pushy(Java APNs library) will take to send 100K push notification?

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications, pushy

I am working on testing the throughput for sending push notification using this library.
If anyone has any idea in this regard, a little guidance would be a great help.
Thanks.

Comment: about 4 seconds. you would have known, if you read the documentation

Comment: Thanks, I have gone through the documentation, might have missed.
could you please help me with the link?

Comment: https://github.com/relayrides/pushy/wiki/Best-practices

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: There is only an answer in form of a comment until now.

**4s** (in words: **four seconds**) seconds as indicated by [XtremeBaumer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7109162/xtremebaumer).

> By contrast, if we send notifications as quickly as we can without waiting for a reply (don't worry—the replies will arrive later), we can go much faster. Even though the server still takes 40 milliseconds to get back to us, we can keep working to send more notifications while we wait. In fact, we could theoretically send up to 25,000
> notifications per second to the same server and under the same network conditions

Taken from https://github.com/relayrides/pushy/wiki/Best-practices

But be are that there might be other limiting factors in this calculation and this is a theorethical limit. Do a loadtest and you'll know for sure...